# Möbius transformation preserving polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field, and $x$ transcendent over $K$. We know that the group of $K$-automorphism of $K(x)$ is $\operatorname{PGL}(2,K)$, whose elements satisfy $ \alpha (x)= \displaystyle \frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$, with $ad-bc \neq 0$.

Given a polynomial $f(x)\in K[x]$, I want to know which automorphism of K(x) fix $f$, it is, $\alpha (f(x)) = f(\alpha(x)) = f(x)$. They form a finite subgroup of $\operatorname{PGL}(2,K)$. Actually, I am interested in the general case when $f\in K(x)$.

For instance, $f(x)=x^n$, with $\operatorname{char} K \nmid n$, is fixed by the ciclic group generated by $x \mapsto \omega x $, where $ \omega$ is a primitive $n-$root of unity. I'd appreciate any help, even if only works for special cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f=\sum_{n=0}^N c_n x^n$ is non-constant then it has a pole at $\infty$ and $f(\alpha(x))$ has a pole at $\alpha^{-1}(\infty)$, for $f$ to be fixed we need $\alpha(\infty)=\infty$. This implies that $\alpha(x)=ax+b$.

Looking at the leading coefficient we must have $a = \zeta_d^k$ with $d| N, \gcd(d,k)=1$.

In characteristic $0$, if $a=1$ then $b=0$ for $f$ having finitely many roots. So assume that $a\ne 1,d\ne 1,char(K)\nmid d$.

> Whence $f(x)=f(\alpha(x))$ iff $f(x-b/(a-1))=f(ax-b/(a-1))$ iff $f(x-b/(a-1))\in K[x^d]$.

When $char(K)\nmid N$ this implies that $N b/(a-1)=c_{N-1}$: so $b/(a-1)$ is known, then find the $d| N$ such that $f(x-b/(a-1))\in K[x^d]$ from which you know the $a$ that will work, and obtain $b$ from $a$.

When $char(K)| N$ it is the same idea, the coefficients of $f$ give a polynomial equation for $b/(a-1)$.

In characteristic $p$ there is also the case $a=1,b\ne 0$ which is a bit different, though $b$ is still given by a polynomial equation in the coefficients.

Comment: The line that claims "If $a=1$ then $b=0$" is not correct. Let $K$ have characteristic $p$: then $x^p-x$ is invariant under $x\mapsto x+1$.

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: @KReiser It is a bit surprising that in characteristic $0$ there are only $\tau(N)$ polynomial shifts to compute, whereas in characteristic $p$ we get some higher polynomial equations. Maybe I am missing something.